angular 17 standalone use multiple components (two components as example)
*self study html, i can deal with css and js, and i can use bootstrap.
*it's first time use front end frameworks.
*English my second language
Angular CLI: 17.3.3
Node: 20.11.1
Package Manager: npm 10.2.4

when i search find that angular 17 is components based.
1- i try build single page application that contain 5 pages, every page contain 5 or 6 different parts (paragraph, table, card, etc), all pages share same header and footer.
2- for simplicity, let's assume i try build SPA that contain:
  2-a. two pages
  2-b. every page contain two different paragraph, overall four paragraph
  2-c. share same header and footer

3- i learn how make the shared header and footer
4- i learn how make navbar work (router every tab to specific one component)
the problem: that i want create separate component for every paragraph. that will produce overall four components, two components for every page.
so how can i set router to show two different components (c1, c2 in first page and c3, c4 in second page) in one page?

You don't have to do anything with router. You just have to use <app-c1></app-c1> in your first component and the same for c2. and in your second page you have to use <app-c3></app-c3> and c4. Let me know if I don't understand your question correctly.

@VarunSavaliya
it's single page app, depend what i found if i use ", N is the component number" for every component they will always appears like header and footer. i try find away to group number of components together and show them in one page, and do the same for next page without using modules. important note am totally new and just start learn angular, so maybe i misunderstand some point

You can create a wrapper component, that contains these two components and set that in routing. The component is just a dummy class required by routing to show the component, please go through the below working example and let me know if any doubts!
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { OneComponent } from './app/one/one.component';
import { TwoComponent } from './app/two/two.component';
import { ThreeComponent } from './app/three/three.component';
import { FourComponent } from './app/four/four.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterModule],
  template: `
    <a [routerLink]="['group1']">group 1 </a> | 
    <a [routerLink]="['group2']">group 2 </a>
    <br/>
    <router-outlet/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

@Component({
  selector: 'wrapper1',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [OneComponent, TwoComponent],
  template: `
    <app-one/>
    <app-two/>
  `,
})
export class WrapperComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
}

@Component({
  selector: 'wrapper2',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ThreeComponent, FourComponent],
  template: `
    <app-three/>
    <app-four/>
  `,
})
export class Wrapper2Component {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter([
      {
        path: 'group1',
        component: WrapperComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'group2',
        component: Wrapper2Component,
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: 'group1',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
    ]),
  ],
});

Stackblitz Demo
